# Forcing y-intercept to zero with Google Earth Engine (GEE) linear interpolation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to use the linear regression function `ee.Reducer.linearFit()` in GEE.

But this function does not provide a mean to force the y-intercept to be equal to 0.

Is there functions I can use to force the y-intercept equal 0 in GEE?

Below is the code example without fixing y-intercept([GEE website](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_regression),  https://code.earthengine.google.com/74570c9f13022e5ee6e058d9fc132087):

```
// Define a list of lists, where columns represent variables. The first column
    // is the independent variable and the second is the dependent variable.
    var listenter code heresVarColumns = ee.List([
      [1, 1],
      [2, 2],
      [3, 3],
      [4, 4],
      [5, 5]
    ]);
    
    // Compute the least squares estimate of a linear function. Note that an
    // object is returned; cast it as an ee.Dictionary to make accessing the
    // coefficients easier.
    var linearFit = ee.Dictionary(listsVarColumns.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit()));
    
    // Inspect the result.
    print(linearFit);
    print('y-intercept:', linearFit.get('offset'));
    print('Slope:', linearFit.get('scale'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute your own linear regression with whatever variables you want.  To force intercept to 0, omit the offset term (

```
var linearFit = ee.Dictionary(listsVarColumns.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(1, 1)));
```